# Ti sensortag CC2650 noise filter

Tags: android, sensors, iot

am using Ti Sensortag cc2650 with an android application. My problem is that the accelerometer and gyroscope output is very noisy. I searched the internet to find any solution for this and I couldn't find anything. Could anyone tell me or guide me for my problem?

I set the advertising frequency to 100ms if that matters.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions for filtering accel and gyro:

- http://www.starlino.com/imu_guide.html
- http://repo.xposed.info/module/net.kajos.gyronoisefilter
- http://www.olliw.eu/2013/imu-data-fusing/
- http://tom.pycke.be/mav/71/kalman-filtering-of-imu-data

Valid google search is "IMU filtering"

Comment: By the way - your frequency is high. Normal. Can decrease if you need

Comment: what frequency do you recommend? 1Hz seemed low to me.

Comment: May decrease to 200 ms advertising (5 Hz) if you want. It's not critical for many cases